# Git apply a patch to the working directory

Tags: git

I have a patch that contains a lot of changes that I would like to split into multiple commits and potentially modify some of the changes.

I want to apply this patch to my working directory and then manually commit the changes. Is it possible to apply a patch to the working directory in git?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use [`git apply`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-apply.html) which applies a patch:

```
git apply < patchname.patch
```

This does not create any commits. In fact, without any options the `git apply` command doesn't even need to have a Git repository. It just applies patches to files.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a `patch` command, e.g.:

```
patch -p1 < path/file.patch
```

When using `patch` command, it will usually auto-detect the format. This is useful when you're trying to apply patch to the working directory which isn't a local checkout of the project you wish to patch.

Otherwise use `git apply` if your patch was created specifically for the project, otherwise it will fail to do anything when used within a local checkout of a git repository.

Answer (score 2):

Try this command line

```
git am < patchname.patch
```

Comment: That does a normal patch apply, adding it to the repository (i.e. a regular commit).