# Applying code patch in GitHub

Tags: git, github

In GitHub, we can create branches, edit files, commit there itself.
I want to know if there is a way I can just copy patch into some editor block and it will apply to the repo's branch?

In short: I want to `git apply <somepatch>` on the GitHub website itself. Does GitHub give that functionality?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git apply a patch to the working directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753056/git-apply-a-patch-to-the-working-directory)

Comment: @SeinopSys sorry you didn't get my question. I want to apply patch to code, on the GitHub website itself, not my local working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now there is no way to apply patches through the GitHub website directly. You need to clone the repository, apply the patch, then push your changes yourself.